# How to set Desktop to show files and folders from different directory?

Tags: unity, nautilus, home-directory, desktop-background

Currently, when all windows are minimized and closed, the desktop will show files and folders located in `/home/user/Desktop`.  I want to change this behavior and have my home folder be displayed for more useful access to my files and directories based on how I organize things.

My question is, how can I tell Unity/Nautilus/Whoever to display files and directories from a different folder on my Desktop Wallpaper?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After doing a search for the string `/Desktop`, I found this setting in `~/.config/user-dirs.dirs`

The setting to change in that file is `XDG_DESKTOP_DIR="$HOME/Desktop"` and you can use whatever directory you like.  I set it to `XDG_DESKTOP_DIR="$HOME"`.

Then log out and back in again.